# Is SWAP used when suspending a computer

Tags: suspend, swap

I know that SWAP is used when putting a computer into hibernation.

But is SWAP used when the computer is suspended?

Answer (score 6):

No, nothing is added to swap. Of course, if there's already stuff in swap, then it will stay there, but you don't need swap space to suspend.

Comment: Say, could you mark my answer as the answer? You can do so using the green check mark along the side of the answer. The check mark is grayed out when deselected and turns green when clicked.

Comment: Interesting. I disabled Swap file and I can no longer suspend the PC